# .slice() second element from array

Tags: javascript

my array:

```
var arr= ["1", "2", "3","4","5", "6", "7","8","9","10","11"];
```

i want to **.slice()** it so output will be:

```
var finalArr = [ "1", "2", "4", "5", "6","9","10","11"];
```

i used sliced like that, but how can i .slice() second element from my array?

```
var b = [].concat(arr.slice(0, 6), arr.slice(-3)); // output: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "9", "10", "11"]
```

**i know about .splice() but that solution doesn't work for my project**

Comment: `[].concat(arr.slice(0, 6), arr.slice(-3));` -> `[].concat(arr.slice(0, 2), arr.slice(3));`

Comment: The final array does not include "3", "7" and "8". Is it intentional or a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of the right 'end' value in the [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) I suppose.

```js
const initial = ["1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];
const finalArr = [ "1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "9", "10", "11"];

// concat the slices
const concatted = initial.slice(0, 2)
  .concat(initial.slice(3, 6))
  .concat(initial.slice(-3));

// or use the spread operator ...
const spreaded = [
  ...initial.slice(0, 2), 
  ...initial.slice(3, 6), 
  ...initial.slice(-3) ];

// or flat three sliced subarrays
const flattened = [
  initial.slice(0, 2), 
  initial.slice(3, 6), 
  initial.slice(-3) ].flat();
  
// or filter all values NOT in finalArr
const notInFinalArray = initial.filter(v => !finalArr.find(fa => fa === v));
const filtered = initial.filter( v => !notInFinalArray.includes(v) );

console.log(`concatted ${JSON.stringify(concatted)} equals finalArr? ${
  JSON.stringify(concatted) === JSON.stringify(finalArr)}`);
console.log(`spreaded ${JSON.stringify(spreaded)} equals finalArr? ${
  JSON.stringify(spreaded) === JSON.stringify(finalArr)}`);
console.log(`flattened ${JSON.stringify(flattened)} equals finalArr? ${
  JSON.stringify(flattened) === JSON.stringify(finalArr)}`);
console.log(`filtered ${JSON.stringify(filtered)} equals finalArr? ${
  JSON.stringify(filtered) === JSON.stringify(finalArr)}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 spread operator:

```
const result = [arr[0], ...arr.slice(2)];
```

Or you can even use `Array.prototype.filter` like so, but be careful of performance if you have big source array:

```
const result = arr.filter((_, index) => index !== 1);
```

Comment: Why do you think `Array.prototype.filter` is more resource intensive than spread operator?

Comment: @jabaa because for slicing you generally copy piece of memory, whereas with filter you call a predicate for each element

Comment: `...arr.slice(0, 1)` is a copy, `...arr.slice(2)` is a copy and `[...arr.slice(0, 1), ...arr.slice(2)]` is a copy, while `arr.filter((_, index) => index !== 1);` in only one copy. That means you need twice the memory for the spread operator in comparison to `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 0):

On your case you can use "push" instead of concat, is more performant:

```js
const arr = ["1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"];

// concat the slices
var finalArr = arr.slice(0, 2);

finalArr.push(...arr.slice(3, 6),...arr.slice(-3));

console.log(`${JSON.stringify(finalArr)}`);
```